# Identify Drill name or type

Tags: mechanical-engineering, drilling

I have this drill and I need one of 6mm, but I don't know how it is called. I think it is used to make a hole round and smooth with high precision. Can anyone identify what the name of this kind of drill is. It is 12mm.

[image: drill]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are *describing* (for finishing holes to precise dimensions, and possibly therefore what you're actually in need of?) is called a "reamer".
There are many types e.g. for use in a machine or by hand, so I will not provide a link lest it be seen as a recommendation

The item in your photo is a "Cylindrical End-Cutting Rotary Burr" for use with a die grinder. See here for an example: https://www.zoro.co.uk/shop/cutting-tools/tct-burrs/carbide-rotary-burrs-cylindrical-end-cutting/f/4165?query=Cylindrical+End-Cutting+Rotary+Burr+12mm

Neither of these things are drill bits.

Comment: Ah, the reamer seems indeed what I need. So this thing I provided in the photo is not ment to do the same as a reamer, right?

Comment: Reamers will not have "teeth" and will have fewer flutes.

Comment: Thanks @Forward Ed - I have corrected the link.